# Benefits for the used animals when producing according to the EU Eco regulation?

Tags: livestock-industry, animal-welfare, labeling, animal-suffering, eu

In 2010, the EU introduced an organic certification label for agricultural products that meet the criteria of the [EU Eco regulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EU-Eco-regulation).

[image: EU organic logo]

Alice doesn’t want to avoid animal products, but she wants to reduce animal suffering stemming from the production of these products.

Does Alice reduce animal suffering when buying animal products bearing this logo compared to the same product not bearing this logo? In other words: **What are the benefits for the used animals?**

(Assume that the rules of the EU Eco regulation are actually followed, so this is not about cases where a product is unjustifiably certified. And assume that non-certified products don’t do better than they are required by law.)

Answer (score 2):

#### Short answer

Yes, Alice reduces animal suffering by buying animal products bearing this logo

#### Long answer

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EU-Eco-regulation) mentions briefly animal welfare as a topic covered by regulation:

> This agreement covers such issues as foodstuffs, disease prevention
> and veterinary treatments, **animal welfare**, **husbandry practices** and the
> management of manure.

[The regulation itself](https://publications.europa.eu/en/publication-detail/-/publication/d839b766-276a-4a46-b26d-7feca84b1876/language-en) provides further information:

In most cases livestock should have **access to free-range exercise areas or grazing**, weather conditions permitting, and such free-range areas should in principle be organised under an appropriate system of rotation;

> Housing for all species of livestock should satisfy the needs of the
> animals concerned as regards ventilation, light, space and comfort and
> sufficient area should accordingly be provided to permit ample freedom
> of movement for each animal and to develop the animal's natural social
> behaviour;